# Soup.select, get only first result back

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to just get the first result back from `for i soup.select(table)`? I just want the first table, every table after it should be ignored. The code is followed by an if statement: `if i.find('th', text = 'Foo'):`

**TLDR;**

Looking for something like this: `if i[0].find('th', text = 'Foo'):`

Comment: Use `soup.find("table").find('th', text = 'Foo')` to get the first

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Then the object is no longer iterable

Comment: @BobWassermann if I am not mistaken you can create another soup object from it.

Comment: @RishavKundu That would be sweet, do you have any reference for this so I can search a bit further?

Comment: Are you trying to find the first table on the page, or the first table in the element you find with soup.select? You can call .find on soup.select(table) so I don't see where the issue is

Comment: @PadraicCunningham First table element. Then putting more statements/checks on this

Comment: @BobWassermann, .find is going to return the first table

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I guess he wants to find the first table which satisfies some conditions.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ``Object has no attribute find``, here's a greater context: https://gist.github.com/BobWassermann/e998fd6fd99d13f53dbb

Comment: @BobWassermann `for i in soup.select('div#mw-content-text table.infobox’)` this can only ever match one element (it’s an ID selector)

Comment: @BobWassermann, can you share the url you want to get the data from?

Comment: @BobWassermann, it’s simple, after doing select, pass the first element of the returned list to the BeautifulSoup constructor, and find will be available.

Comment: @RishavKundu wrong: in this html `<div id="mw-content-text"><table class="infobox" /><table class="infobox" /></div>` your selector `soup.select('div#mw-content-text table.infobox’)` will match twice

Comment: @mescalinum ah yes, I made a mistake, there are two selectors there.

Comment: @mescalinum but the general idea holds, you can create new soup objects from the elements returned by `select`.

Comment: yes, and anyway the `bs4.element.Tag` class (returned by most of BS methods) has the same BS methods, so you can chain methods like `soup.find('tag').select('my#cool css .selector)[0].find('anothertag')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to `break` right after the first iteration:

```
for i in soup.select('table'):
    if i.find('th', text = 'Foo'):
        ...
    break
```

Another one is to chain methods, and catch exception if element not found:

```
try:
    el = soup.select('table')[0].find('th', text='Foo')
except AttributeError, TypeError:
    print('element not found')
```

Note: `soup.select('table')[0]` and `soup.find('table')` give the same result

Comment: Your answer is better.